# Compiler policies on destruction of temporaries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, intel

I've been playing with the following piece of code. `file_string` returns a temporary string that should only "live" until the end of the statement. In Visual Studio 2008, when you use `pTempFolder`, it contains rubbish as expected. In Linux though, with Intel compiler 11.0, `pTempFolder` still points to a valid string. Do compilers have different policies regarding the destruction of temporaries, kind of eager (Visual) versus lazy (Intel)? Or maybe this is just a coincidence?

```
boost::filesystem wpathTempFolder("/tmp");
const wchar_t* const pTempFolder = wpathTempFolder.file_string().c_str();
// use pTempFolder
```

BTW, that is boost filesystem version 2. I've also seen that `file_string` is being deprecated in boost filesystem version 3. And that there is a new `c_str` method that operates over a string&, instead of over a temporary string.

```
/*filesystem 2*/
const string_type file_string() const;
/*filesystem 3*/
const string_type&  native() const;  // native format, encoding
const value_type*   c_str() const;   // native().c_str()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely, the string is still invalid, it just so happens that that section of memory hasn't yet been de-allocated at the operating system level and it "happens" to work. This program exhibits undefined behaviour- which always includes "may continue to work as if nothing went wrong". Visual Studio is completely correct here to crash your program or pretty much anything.

Comment: Just a nit, but that should be "deallocated or overwritten".  It's undefined behavior to access data after it's lifetime has ended, so anything can happen.

Comment: @James: If it wasn't overwritten, he wouldn't get rubbish, he'd get a perfectly good string.

Comment: If the memory is actually returned to the OS, he could get a crash when he tried to access it.  (Not really a crash, but Purify or Valgrind will complain as well.  Even if the data read seems correct.)

Comment: @James, an actual crash is possible if the page in which the memory resides is actually deallocated by the OS. Then even reading would cause an invalid access (segfault on linux). Though I think normal heap memory on linux is never actually returned to the kernel, but on windows I think malloc does allocate page based, so it is more likely to actually crash on windows.

Comment: Clear. I was wondering if the behaviour I was getting in Linux was more than a coincidence, and if some compilers might delay the destruction of stack temporaries until the end of a function. I guess that simply doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

The lifetime of a temporary (with a few exceptions) is until the
end of the full expression.  The lifetime of the array object pointed to
by the return value of `std::string::c_str()` does not excede
that of the string object itself (and may be shorter, if any
non-const functions are called on the string).  Accessing an
object after its lifetime has ended is undefined behavior, so
you cannot draw any conclusions from what the compiler does.

Comment: curious now about the "few exceptions".

Comment: @rturrando There are a few "Singleton" whose role involves cleanup---I use a Singleton which manages temporary files, for example, deleting them (or not) at the end of the program.  Such singleton cannot be used in destructors (since they may not exist then), but are also useful (and if you need to create a temporary file in a destructor, you're doing too much in the destructor).

Comment: Why not just allocate such objects on the stack of `main`? There's no need to resort to Singletons.

Comment: @DeadMG I'm not sure which objects we're talking about.  Somehow some comments are appearing here which are relevant to another thread.  If it's a question of singletons, however, the usual reason for using a singleton in C++ is because you may need it in constructors of static objects---the usual singleton idiom in C++ is used more often to solve the order of initialization problem than for anything else.